# Q:[Z3] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.z3.Native

Tags: maven, z3

when I use the maven dependency like this

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.sosy-lab</groupId>
      <artifactId>javasmt-solver-z3</artifactId>
      <version>z3-4.4.1-1558-gf96cfea</version>
</dependency>
```

then I use the example of java

```
public void simpleExample()
{

    System.out.println("SimpleExample");
    try {
        Log.open("SimpleExample");
        Log.append("SimpleExample");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        Log.close();
    }

    {
        Context ctx = new Context();
        /* do something with the context */

        /* be kind to dispose manually and not wait for the GC. */
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

once I use the Native.java ,just show this problem,what is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: Upon the first call of a Z3-function, do you get a "DLL not found" type of error or does everything work except for one of the Z3-related functions in Native.java?

Answer (score 0):

To use the Java API you should set your environment variable in your IDE as follows:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path_to_build_folder_of_z3_source

just follow instructions in [this](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) page to build the source code.